# How to find points of certain distance on a circle perimeter?

Tags: math, geometry, equation

Suppose, `(x1, y1)` is a point on the perimeter of a circle `(x-420)^2 + (y-540)^2 = 260^2` what are the two points on the circle perimeter of distance `d`(euclidean) from the point `(x1, y1)`

Comment: How is this related to programming? Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Are you good at trigonometry? **Try a simpler question:** given a unit circle, and think about the two points a distance `d` from the point (1,0)? Pick the point in the upper half-plane (y>0) and write the equation that relates d to theta.

Comment: `d` is arclength or euqlidean distance ?  `a = atan2(y1-540,x1-420); xx=420+260*cos(a+/-da);  yy=540+260*sin(a+/-da);` where `da= d/260;` for arclength and for euqlidean `da=2*asin(d/(2*260));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using trig

Assuming you are using a programming language. The answer is using pseudo code.

Using [radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) the distance `d` along a circle can be expressed as an angle `a` computed as `a = d / r` (where `r` is the radius)

Given an arbitrary point on the circle. `(x1-420)^2 + (y1-540)^2 = 260^2` *(**NOTE** assumes x1, y1 are known)* we can extract the center is `x = 420`, `y = 540`, and radius `r = 260`

The angular distance d is then `a = d / 260`.

Most languages have the function [atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) which will compute the angle of a vector, We can get the angle from the circle center to the arbitrary point as `ang = atan2(y1 - 540, x1 - 420)` (*Note `y` first then `x`*)

Thus the absolute angles from the arbitrary point `{x1, y1}` to the points `d` distance along the circle (`ang1` , `ang2`) is computed as...

```
// ? represents known unknowns
x = 420
y = 540
r = 260
d = ?
x1 = ?
y1 = ?
ang = atan2(y1 - y, x1 - x)
ang1 = ang + d / r
ang2 = ang - d / r
```

And the coordinates of the points (`px1`, `py1`, `px2`, `py2`) computed as...

```
px1 = cos(ang1) * r + x
py1 = sin(ang1) * r + y

px2 = cos(ang2) * r + x
py2 = sin(ang2) * r + y
```

### Vector algebra

The problem can also be solved using vector algebra and does not require the trig function `atan2`

Compute the unit vector representing the angle `a = d / r` and then with the circle at the origin, transform (rotate) the point on the circle using the unit vector in both directions. Translate the points back to the circles original position for the solution.